# How to check a slice for an element and manipulate another slice if value exists or doesn't

Tags: go

I am writing a program in Go which should check a slice for a name. If the name exists, it should enter "YES" in another slice and "NO" if it doesn't exist. The name slice should be entered by the user and the checking should start while entering values.

I have written some code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var limit int
    var names string
    fmt.Scanln(&limit)
    arr := make([]string, limit)
    yn := make([]string, limit)
    for i := 0; i < limit; i++ {
        fmt.Scanln(&names)
        for _, a := range arr {
            if a == names {
                yn = append(yn, "YES")
            } else {
                arr = append(arr, names)
                yn = append(yn, "NO")
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(yn)
}
```

The output should be like

User entered values:

5

steve

john

rainn

jenna

john

Output:

NO

NO

NO

NO

YES

The error i was getting was a big array of a bunch of YES and NO values with 2 empty elements in the begining.

Comment: What doesn't seem to work? What error or other unexpected output do you see?

Comment: You're ignoring errors. Never do that.

Comment: Aside from that, the logic in your code is clearly wrong. If you just step through your for loop, you'll see that you're appending to your slices _for every element_, not once per input.

Comment: @Flimzy sorry dude this is actually my FIRST program in Go. I'm just learning.

Comment: There's nothing to apologize about. But the problems with your code are not primarily Go-related. They're logic related.

Comment: @Flimzy duly noted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## First solution

here is what you want:

```
func main() {

    var limit int
    var name string
    _, err := fmt.Scanln(&limit)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    var names []string
    var presence []string

    for i := 0; i < limit; i++ {

        _, err := fmt.Scanln(&name)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        var exist = false
        for _, a := range names {
            if a == name {
                exist = true
                break
            }
        }

        if !exist {
            names = append(names, name)
            presence = append(presence, "NO")
        } else {
            presence = append(presence, "YES")
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(presence)
}
```

- First of all [Scanln](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scanln) returns the `error` and you need to check it.
- Second: append to array must be outside the inner loop. Try to use debug `Println()` to debug your algorithm.

## Move code to separate function

To make things clear I offer to move check of existance to separate function:

```
func exists(a []string, element string) bool {
    for _, e := range a {
        if e == element {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}

func main() {
    var limit int
    var name string
    _, err := fmt.Scanln(&limit)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    var names []string
    var presence []string

    for i := 0; i < limit; i++ {

        _, err := fmt.Scanln(&name)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        if !exists(names, name) {
            names = append(names, name)
            presence = append(presence, "NO")
        } else {
            presence = append(presence, "YES")
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(presence)
}
```

## Optimization

In the previous code we pass array of string to function each time on every loop. If the array will be bigger it is not good, and it will be better to pass pointer to array of string to a function (or array of pointers to the strings).

Comment: That's still not right. You'll still end up with a slice front-padded with a bunch of empty values.

Comment: @Flimzy, thank you - I have forgot about it. Fixed the code.